# How to manually click a Jquery multiselect box?

Tags: jquery

I have a few multi select boxes on a page. When the user clicks a certain checkbox, I would like one of the multiselect boxes on the page to automatically be clicked with a certain value. Do you have any idea of how to do this?

Thank you!

```
$("#select_country").multiselect({
  multiple: false,
  header: "Select a country",
  noneSelectedText: "Select a country",
  selectedList: 1
});
```

======
so far I've tried these methods with no success:

```
$("#select_country").multiselect("widget").find("input:checkbox").each(function(){
  this.click();
 }); 

$("#select_country").multiselect("widget").find("input:checkbox").triggerHandler('click');

$("#select_country").trigger('click');
```

Comment: By `multiselect` you're referring to a jQuery UI widget or a plugin? If so, please provide a link, since this is not a default jQuery functionality.

Comment: thanks. http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ is a great resource and the source is listed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps (demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/ehynds/PKypd/):

```
var second = $("#select_something").multiselect();

$("#select_country").multiselect({
    multiple: false,
    header: "Select a country",
    noneSelectedText: "Select a country",
    selectedList: 1,
    click: function( event, ui ) {

        // if the user clicks "usa", check the first box
        // in the second select.  if the user selects "canada",
        // check the second box.
        //
        // the call to filter() ensures that the items from the
        // second select remain selected if the user chooses
        // the same item from the first select multiple times.
        //
        // you can easily swap out .eq() for another filter()
        // and to choose checkboxes by value instead of their
        // position.
        second.multiselect('widget')
            .find(':checkbox')
            .eq(ui.value === 'usa'? 0 : 1)
            .filter(':not(:checked)')
            .each(function(){
                this.click();
            });
    }
});
```

Also, don't forget that multiselect is simply a visual enhancement to the underlying select box.  Any changes you make in multiselect are also made on the select element itself, and vice versa. Therefore, you don't have to mess around figuring how to do this in multiselect; you can make an option tag selected in the original select box, and call `.multiselect('refresh')` to tell the widget to refresh itself.

You are correct about calling `.click()` on the DOM node, not `triggerHandler()` or `$.fn.click()`. The reason is because of [this bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/3827) in jQuery, where trigger("click") calls the handler before the checkbox native click() method.

Comment: selecting the option tag in the original select box without calling on multiselect worked great... but calling refresh did not update the title of the box. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What version of multiselect are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#select_country").multiselect("widget").find(":radio[value='PUT_YOUR_VALUE']").each(function() {
     this.click();
});
$("#select_country").multiselect('refresh');
```